# External api connection is getting disconnected after 4 hours of build of tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpurlconnection

(httpurlconnection** using this class to connect with exernal API))

We are calling external API for a purpose.So, After 4hours not getting response from from source.getting the above exception after four hours.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method
>   name. HTTP method names must be tokens at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:428)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:684)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: we have problem with httpurlconnection.I shared particular exception in the body.And After restart of application the issue is getting lost.Only the session is working for 4 hours from the start of application.

Comment: Please you can edit your question and add the details